# Can I include the all JSON paths required in a JSON file and use it inside my feature file for match or anything else?

Tags: karate

For eg, I save paths.json and add the following. I know there is a mistake in the way i try, but not able to find it

```
{
  "name": "JSON Path's",
  "description": "This mainly store the paths of the JSON elements which are validated in each scenario",
  "SC_4": {
    "appHeader": "$.testResponse.applicationHeader",
    "ProductsAction": "$.testResponse.applicationHeader.item.action"
  }
} 


* def attributes = read('../jsonpaths/paths.json')
Given url endPointURL
And request baseJsonRequest
When method post
Then status 200
* def appHeaderSecondTry = attributes.SC_4.appHeader
* print appHeaderSecondTry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow you are getting to be a power user of Karate so soon :P

Okay, personally I don't recommend trying to build a mini-framework over Karate like you are doing, I can see what you are trying to do - keep all assertions "declarative" and try to re-use common code for the actual HTTP call etc.

My opinionated take on this is, you save very few lines of code (because of how easy it is to make an HTTP request in Karate). Also, you should be able to re-use a feature file via the `call` keyword. I would urge you to try and keep the match statements "normal" in your tests.

That said, what you are missing is the `karate.eval()` operation, look for it in the doc. Here is an example (line 91): [`js-arrays.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/demos/js-arrays.feature#L91)